# How to access jquery taphold inside other function

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, canvas, touch

I have a canvas with objects inside and have a event handler for object:selected. When I select the object, a div (vtover) appears at the mouse/touch pointer by pageX and pageY.

What I want to accomplish is to change the event handler from click to touch taphold using jQuery Mobile. I tried to put all code inside my taphold, but that didnt work.

How can I solve this?

chartdiv is the id of my canvas container

## Code

```
canvas.observe("object:selected", function (e) {
    $("#chartdiv").on("taphold", function (a) {
       // tried to put below code inside this, but this didnt work out.
    });
    var obj = e.target;
    $("#vtover").show();
    $("#vtover").offset({
        left: event.pageX,
        top: event.pageY - 200
    });
    $("#vt_vol").val(myvol.toLocaleString("de-DE") + " " + unit);
    $("#vt_period").val(myper + " Tage");
    $("#vt_sump").val(sumper.toLocaleString("de-DE") + " " + unit);
    $("#vt_diffp").val(Math.round((myvol * myper / sumper) * 100) + " %");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, at least not like that, this should work:

```
var canvasHandler  = {
    obj : null
}

canvas.observe("object:selected", function (e) {
    canvasHandler.obj = e.target;
});

$(document).on("taphold", "#chartdiv",function (a) {

    // Now if you need selected canvas just use canvasHandler.obj

    $("#vtover").show();
    $("#vtover").offset({
        left: event.pageX,
        top: event.pageY - 200
    });
    $("#vt_vol").val(myvol.toLocaleString("de-DE") + " " + unit);
    $("#vt_period").val(myper + " Tage");
    $("#vt_sump").val(sumper.toLocaleString("de-DE") + " " + unit);
    $("#vt_diffp").val(Math.round((myvol * myper / sumper) * 100) + " %");
});
```